# MySQL command-line dont work

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, command-line, lamp

I have an Ubuntu-Server with LAMP. Now if I try to execute something in the command-line I just get no answer, and the command don't work.

```
#mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@10.4.0.109 INDENTIFIED BY "MYPASSWORD"
    ->
```

This -> is everything I got. No Query OK or some errors. Why is wont work? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if root has the privileges after executing the order?

Comment: use the delimiter ";" by default

Comment: @KishorKundan That was an answer. =)

Comment: It was the delimiter. Thank you very much. But why do i have to make a delimiter if i just have one line? i don't get it

Comment: Because a query can have multiple lines

Comment: So i can enter one line then press enter, and add the second line with a ';'?

Comment: @DreamEater, Yes but it was so small that didn't feel like an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a ";" to close your query otherwise Mysql doesn't close it.